# How to create a 'add more' feature in HTML forms

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am creating a HTML form in which I need to create a 'add more' button so another field appears. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible in pure HTML, but it can easily be achieved using javascript!

### Basic example

In the basic example, you have one input field. When you click the <kbd>add field</kbd> button an extra input gets added after the last inserted input.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add_field', function() {
  $('<input type="text" class="input" name="field[]" value="">').insertAfter('.input:last');
})
```

```css
form {
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="input" name="field[]" value="">
</form>

<button type="button" class="add_field">Add field</button>
```

---

### Copy value

This example is almost the same as the example above with one difference. It copies the value of the previous input. This is done with help of the JQuery `.val()` method

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add_field', function() {
  let value = $('.input:last').val(); // gets the value of the previous input
  $('<input type="text" class="input" name="field[]" value="' + value + '">').insertAfter('.input:last');
})
```

```css
form {
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="input" name="field[]" value="">
</form>

<button type="button" class="add_field">Add field</button>
```

---

### Input groups

You could also copy an entire input group with multiple input fields.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add_field', function() {
  $('<div class="input-group"><input type="email" class="input" name="email[]" value="" placeholder="Your email"><input type="password" class="input" name="password[]" value="" placeholder="Your password"></div>').insertAfter('.input-group:last');
})
```

```css
form {
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.input-group {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="email" class="input" name="email[]" value="" placeholder="Your email">
    <input type="password" class="input" name="password[]" value="" placeholder="Your password">
  </div>
</form>

<button type="button" class="add_field">Add field</button>
```

If you need any more examples please leave a comment!

Answer (score 2):

In a few lines of js and html you can get that :

```
<button class="add-input">Add one more input</button>
<form action="." method="GET">
    <div class="inputs">
        <input type="text" name="text[]">
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
    const addButton = document.querySelector('button.add-input')

    const inputDiv = document.querySelector('form .inputs')

    addButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{ // button to add the inputs
        let newInput = document.createElement('input')
        newInput.name = 'text[]' // add the name of the input
        newInput.type = 'text' // add the type of the input

        // you can add other attributes before appeding the node into the html

        inputDiv.appendChild(newInput)
    })

</script>
```

and you will have this as a result (I used php to prompt the result)

[image: Result]

you can add as many input you want/need.

Next step is just doing some css

Answer (score 1):

Please try instead,

```js
$(".Addmore").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // make a separation line
  $("#FormItems").append('<hr width="300px">');
  
  // append the input field as your needs
  $("#FormItems").append('<input name="user" type="text" placeholder="Username"><br>');
  $("#FormItems").append('<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address">');

});
```

```css
.formwrapper{
  text-align:center;
}
input{
  padding:3px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="formwrapper">
  <form>
    <div id="FormItems">
        <input name="user" type="text" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Add More" class="Addmore">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Hari can you check this snippet. What is actually you want ? please add description or screenshot or improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is, what you mean

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="cta">
</form>
<button>Add More</button>

<script>
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let field = document.createElement('input');
    // change field however you'd like
    document.querySelector('form').insertBefore(field, document.querySelector('form:last-child'));
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create this using HTML only, you will need javascript. You could use a frontend framework like react.js to make life easy.

For example in react, you could bind an onclick listener on the button and maintain an array of values as state. Use this array to map value to your input. Whenever user clicks the button, you can then simply push a defaultValue to the array and react will handle the rest.

```
Import React, { useState }  from 'react';

const Page = ()=>{
    const [ arr, setArr ] = useState([""]);
    const handleAdd = ()=>{
         setArr([...arr, ""]);
    };
    
    return <form>
        {arr.map((elem, index)=><input 
            onChange={ //"implement logic to update value stored in array" }
            value={elem}
            key={index} /> )}
         <button onClick={()=>handleAdd()}>Add</button>
    </form>

}
```

Comment: You're right on the HTML and Javascript part, but using a framework for just adding some forms seems a little overkill. Besides Hari doesn't say that it should be made in React.js

Comment: I just gave an example for general idea. You can of course use manual DOM manipulation for simple use.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Bootstrap and jquery**

Only in html is not possible, you need some on click event to trigger the functionality that may change the html dom.
You can use vanilla javascript as well, here is example using jquery library.

It will dynamically add and remove the element

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>YDNJSY</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
       

</head>

<body>
    <!-- <h1>Lets learn javascript</h1> -->
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3> Actions</h3>
            <div id="field">
                <div id="field0">
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="action_id">Action Id</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input id="action_id" name="action_id" type="text" placeholder=""
                                class="form-control input-md">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="action_name">Action Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input id="action_name" name="action_name" type="text" placeholder=""
                                class="form-control input-md">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button id="add-more" name="add-more" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="./index.js"></script>

</html>
```

**index.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var next = 0;
    $("#add-more").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var addto = "#field" + next;
        var addRemove = "#field" + (next);
        next = next + 1;
        var newIn = ' <div id="field' + next + '" name="field' + next + '"><!-- Text input--><div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="action_id">Action Id</label> <div class="col-md-5"> <input id="action_id" name="action_id" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"> </div></div><br><br> <!-- Text input--><div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="action_name">Action Name</label> <div class="col-md-5"> <input id="action_name" name="action_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"> </div></div><br><br></div>';
        var newInput = $(newIn);
        var removeBtn = '<button id="remove' + (next - 1) + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-me" >Remove</button></div></div><div id="field">';
        var removeButton = $(removeBtn);
        $(addto).after(newInput);
        $(addRemove).after(removeButton);
        $("#field" + next).attr('data-source', $(addto).attr('data-source'));
        $("#count").val(next);

        $('.remove-me').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1);
            var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
            $(this).remove();
            $(fieldID).remove();
        });
    });

});
```